# How to replace a string of digits with a padded version of that string using regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, padding

I have a program that searches through a directory loading files into DB, matching filenames with ID field in DB, using regex to search for patterns.

DB contains ID(`##AAA######`, ex `14ABC000123`) while filename usually contains `##AAA###` (ex `14ABC123`), and I need regex that would match these two, returning full ID from filename. Until now I devised

```
([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{1,6})
```

but when returning $1$2$3 to the matcher it misfires saying that `14ABC123 != 14ABC000123`. Please help.

Comment: Where/what is the matcher? The statement it's returning you is certainly true... What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to get rid of zeroes. Try this:

```
([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})0*?([1-9]{1,6})
```

Comment: This won't catch an "ID number" (after the 0s) of `102`. There's no need to make the quantifier lazy here, you can simply use [`([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})0*([0-9]+)`](http://regex101.com/r/iI4gN5/2)